# Python: how to extend Voronoi cells to the boundary of the geometry?

Tags: python, geopandas, voronoi

I have two geopandas dataframes `dfMd` and `centers`. `dfMd` is made by polygons while `centers` by points. [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1DcZqNoQWj8Rd8dusgnccCV5eiv-t1V8H?usp=sharing) the link to the files.

```
f,ax=plt.subplots()
dfMd.plot(ax=ax, column='volume')
centers.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
```

[image]

I would like to generate the `Voronoi` tasselation of the points extended to the entire geometry. This is what I am doing:

```
from shapely.geometry import mapping
g = [i for i in centers.geometry]
coords = []
for i in range(0, len(g)):
    coords.append(mapping(g[i])["coordinates"]) # for first feature/row

from libpysal.cg.voronoi  import voronoi, voronoi_frames

regions, vertices = voronoi(coords)
region_df, point_df = voronoi_frames(coords)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
region_df.plot(ax=ax, color='white',edgecolor='black', lw=3)
dfMd.plot(ax=ax, column='volume',alpha=0.1)
point_df.plot(ax=ax, color='red')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
region_df.plot(ax=ax, color='white',edgecolor='black', lw=3)
dfMd.plot(ax=ax, column='volume',alpha=0.1)
point_df.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
```

[image]

How can I extend the `Voronoi` region to the external boundary of my `dfMd`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an option `clip=box()` within `voronoi_frames()`. Relevant code follows.

```
from shapely.geometry import box

region_df, point_df = voronoi_frames(coords, clip=box(-4.2, 40.15, -3.0, 40.85))
```

[image: voronoi]